# Sort text field

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following records and need to sort them accordingly:

```
AB*1
AB*2
AB*10
AB*100
```

I am using the following SQL Statement which works perfectly, BUT only for records which are filtered to a specific criteria.

```
SELECT      Column1 
FROM        dbo.Table1 
ORDER BY    LEN(Column1), Column1
WHERE Column1 Like 'AB*'
```

When I remove the Where clause in the example, the record AB*100 appears way down below. Obiously, it has grouped together all the records with the Length of 4 then it starts all over with the records with length of 5 and so on.

Is it possible to order these so all before the asterisk are grouped together and sorted correctly?

Comment: Always 2 characters before the asterisk?

Comment: Sadly, no. Also. was about to add that after the asterisk, for the most part, are numerical but very few are in alphanumeric (Ex. 1A, 2A, etc.)

Comment: Please give more heterogeneous input an desired output. You want this in Access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely to be slow:

```
ORDER BY Mid(Column1,1,Instr(Column1,"*"))
```

Edit re comment

```
SELECT Column1
FROM Table
ORDER BY Mid([Column1],1,InStr([Column1],"*")), 
         Val(Mid([Column1],InStr([Column1],"*")+1));
```

Sample data used in test:

```
ID
ab*1
ab*10
ab*2
abcdef*a1
abcdef*10
abcdef*40a
```

For nulls, just add a few zero-length strings.

```
SELECT column1
FROM Table
ORDER BY Mid([column1] & "",1,InStr([column1] & "","*")),
         Val(Mid([column1] & "",InStr([column1] & "","*")+1));
```

Comment: Not as slow, but produces the following order: AB*1, AB*12, AB*14, AB*10, AB*11, AB*13, AB*5, AB*2...

Comment: Tried the following:  ORDER BY Mid(Column1,1,Instr(Column1,"*")) ASC, Mid(Column1,InStr(Column1,"*")+1,Len(Column1)) ASC but get a  “Data Type mismatch in criteria expression” error message. My idea was to try to sort befre the asterisk and then after, but some have letters.

Comment: Hi @Rick, I was not quite sure what you wanted. I have added a note.

Comment: Still get the mismatch error. Tried just with the second sort to test.

Comment: I have posted sample data that worked for me. Can you post a sample that includes more examples?

Comment: I'm guessing it has to with Nulls in the filed

Comment: You just need some ZLSs. I have added a note above.

Comment: I added a where clause: `where Column1 is not null`. Also added Column as the third sort to deal with the values without an asterisk. 'where Column1 is not null
ORDER BY Mid([Column1],1,InStr([Column1],"*")), 
         Val(Mid([Column1],InStr([Column1],"*")+1)), Column1' Thanks!

Comment: I like the ZLS idea. No need for the where clause.

Answer (score 2):

The first character "alphabetically" is actually "no character".  So it's not so much that "a string of 4 comes first".  For example, the following are in order...

```
AB*1
AB*2
AB*10
AB*100 
CD*1
CD*2
CD*10
CD*100
```

You *could* order by the first 3 characters as a string, and the trailing characters as a number.  Provided that's how your data behaves...

```
ORDER BY
  LEFT(column1, 3),
  CLNG(MID(column1, 4, 8000))
```

Or you could pad out your values and order them *as if* they looked like this...

```
AB*100 
AB*10Z
AB*1ZZ
AB*2ZZ
```

Using this kind of ORDER BY statement...

```
ORDER BY
  column1 & string(8000 - LEN(column1), "z")
```

But these are all work-arounds to force an 'un-natural' ordering, as at present you're getting the 'correct' ordering.

Comment: How do you see CAST working with MS Access? (SQL is a generic tag.)

Comment: @Remou - Doh, I checked the `padright()` equivilent, but not the CAST.   It should be...  *`CLNG()`*

Comment: On both examples I get the error: "Data type mismatch criteria in expression". Before the asterisk there is no set length, could be one character or four.

Comment: @Rick - You need to tightly define the exact problem space.  Please can you provide exact rules for what ***all*** the possible value can look like?

Answer (score 1):

it seems this will do what you want, unless I misunderstand

```
SELECT      Column1 
FROM        dbo.Table1 
ORDER BY    left(Column1,2), LEN(Column1)
```